# How to count the times of string occur in a worksheet (using C#)

Tags: c#, excel

I have a question is how to count the times of string or character occur.

for example:
there is a worksheet with some strings in it: Hello, my name is Ellen. My favorite sport is basketball....

now I want to find the string "is". as you can see, the string "is" shows two times. so I will get the result is 2.

could anyone help me?
thank u all.

```
Excel.Range cells = ws.Cells;

match = cells.Find(
          What: what,
          After: Type.Missing,
          LookIn: Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas,
          LookAt: Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
          SearchDirection: Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext
        );

if (match == null)
   log.Debug(xlDWorkBook.Name + "-" + xlSheet.Name + "找不到「" + what + "」");
else
{
   log.Debug(xlDWorkBook.Name + "-" + xlSheet.Name + "共找到: " + count + "個「" + what + "」，並以「" + replacement + "」完成取代");
```

Comment: Explain "tried but failed".  What did that consist of, all day?  What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it!
I think I don't work with the Find function correctly before. The Find function finds the first occurrence, not all occurrences.
[How To: Programmatically Search for Text in Worksheet Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-search-for-text-in-worksheet-ranges)

```
                int count = 0;

                match = cells.Find(
                        What: what,
                        After: Type.Missing,
                        LookIn: Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas,
                        LookAt: Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                        SearchDirection: Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext);

                Excel.Range firstMatch = null;

                while (match != null)
                {
                    if (firstMatch == null)
                    {
                        firstMatch = match;
                    }

                    // If you didn't move to a new range, you are done.
                    else if (match.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1)
                          == firstMatch.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1))
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    count++;
                    match = cells.FindNext(match);
                }

                cells.Replace(
                    what,
                    replacement,
                    Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                    Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns,
                    false
                );

                log.Debug(xlDWorkBook.Name + "-" + xlSheet.Name + "共找到: " + count + "個「" + what + "」，並以「" + replacement + "」完成取代");
```

thanks every help: )